# Environment variable in GitHub Actions not interpolated correctly

Tags: github, continuous-integration, environment-variables, github-actions

In the beginning of a (re-usable) workflow

```yaml
env:
  STAGING_GCR_PROJECT: my-project-id
```

and when using it

```yaml
  slack_staging_success:
    needs: build_staging
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ always() && contains(join(needs.*.result, ','), 'success') }}
    env:
      STAGING_IMAGE: "gcr.io/$STAGING_GCR_PROJECT/${{ inputs.image_name }}:${{ inputs.image_tag }}"

    
    steps:
      
    - name: slack success for staging
      uses: rtCamp/action-slack-notify@v2
      env:
        SLACK_ICON: $SLACK_ICON_SUCCESS
        SLACK_COLOR: green
        SLACK_MESSAGE: "STAGING image ${{ env.STAGING_IMAGE }} was built / pushed with SUCCESS"
```

In Slack the message interpolates as

> STAGING image gcr.io/$STAGING_GCR_PROJECT/echo-server:1.0.2 failed to be built

Why isn't `$STAGING_GCR_PROJECT` interpolated correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported at the moment, to have env variable inside env.

The [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#env) on env mentions it:

> variables in the env map cannot be defined in terms of other variables in the map.

Answer (score -1):

In order to use workflow environment variables, use the prefix `env.` and enclose it in `${{ }}` just like you did with the inputs:

```yaml
env:
  STAGING_IMAGE: "gcr.io/${{ env.STAGING_GCR_PROJECT }}/${{ inputs.image_name }}:${{ inputs.image_tag }}"
```

Comment: I am getting this now `Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within expression: env.STAGING_GCR_PROJECT`

Comment: ah perhaps you can't use `env` within another `env`. What you could do instead is declare an input with `required: false` and `default: my-project-id` and then change that `env` to `inputs`

Comment: @rethab Thanks for that input on using the inputs default. Great workaround to use env variable within an env variable.